# cannot get my python program to run the whole program

Tags: python-3.x

It won't make any calculations. I've tried everything and can               usually get a program to run. Been at it for 3 days now. Any
suggestions?

here is my program:
  I want my program to determine which tax bracket to apply to my user's gross income. Then determine if the user qualifies for the 2 tax  credits designated. If the Net amount is greater than 0 the user owes...If the net amount is less than 0, the user has a refund coming in that amount. It always stops after the user inputs his gross income. But there are not any errors.

> ```
> # ITC 1353 SEC.2
> # wayne_jones_Lab2.py
> # oct_24,_2011
>
> # This program defines my 5 tax brackets with corresponding tax rates
> # and defines my 2 tax credits and the amounts for each. It          will then
> # get the user's gross income to figure the amount of tax the user will owe.
> # It then will subtract tax owed from gross income which equals the net
> # income. Tax credits will be deducted from the net income to enter the amount
> # owed by the user. If the amount is less than 0, it will enter the amount
> # to be refunded to user.
>
> # Global constants
> # TAXBRACKET1 <= 10000 # RATE1 IS 0.01
> # TAXBRACKET2 <= 30000
> # TAXBRACKET3 <= 50000
> # TAXBRACKET4 <= 100000
> # TAXBRACKET5  > 100001
> # TAX_CREDIT1  =$1000
> # TAX_CREDIT2  =$3000 
> # TAX_OWED = GROSS_INCOME * RATE 
> # RATE1(0.01)
> # RATE2(0.10)
> # RATE3(0.15)
> # RATE4(0.20)
> # RATE5(0.25)
> # GROSS_INCOME = 0.00
> # TAX_OWED = 0.00
>
> def main():
>     # get user's gross income
>     # display gross income
>     gross_income = int(input('enter the users gross income: '))                                               
>     print('users gross income is $', format(gross_income, '.2f'))
>
> def tax_rate():
>     # Calculate and display the tax rate
>     # calculate the tax owed.
>     tax_owed = (GROSS_INCOME * RATE)
>     # display the tax owed.
>     print('Amount tax owed is $', format(tax, '.2f'))
>     if gross_income < 10000:
>         RATE1 = 0.01
>     elif gross_income >= 10001 and gross_income <= 30000:
>         RATE2 = 0.10 
>     elif gross_income >= 30001 and gross_income <= 50000:
>         RATE3 = 0.15
>     elif gross_income >= 50001 and gross_income <= 100000:
>         RATE4 = 0.20
>     else:
>         RATE5 = 0.25
>         calc_tax_owed(gross_income, rate)
>
> def tax_owed():
>     def calc_tax_owed(gross_income, rate):
>         # calculate the tax owed.
>         tax_owed = (GROSS_INCOME * RATE)
>         # display the tax owed.
>         print('Amount tax owed is $', format(tax, '.2f'))
>
>     # determine if qualify for tax credit1
>     if user_qualify_taxcredit1:
>             tax_owed = (gross_income * rate) - 1000
>     else:
>             tax_owed = gross_income * rate
>
>     # determine if qualify for tax credit2
>     if user_qualify_taxcredit2:
>             tax_owed = (gross_income * rate) - 3000
>     else:
>             tax_owed = gross_income * rate
>
>     # determine if amount owed is < or > 0
>     if amount > 0:
>             print('The tax owed is $', format(tax, '.2f'))
>     else:
>             print('user recieves Refund of $', format(Refund, '.2f'))
>
> main()
> ```

Comment: Is this homework? In that case tag it as such.

Answer (score 3):

I would vote for close for being too localized if your problem wasn’t so obvious: The script calls `main` which asks for user input, and then prints that exact data. There are no calls to the other functions, and nothing else is actually done, so of course, you won’t get any additional output.

And btw. calling the other functions will lead to a lot of reference errors, because you are using variables without them being defined.

For `tax_rate` unknown variables are: `GROSS_INCOME`, `RATE`, `tax`, `gross_income` (it’s defined in `main` and as such only available there), `calc_tax_owed` (the function is defined within `tax_owed` and as such only available there), `rate`.

For `tax_owed` unknown variables are: `user_qualify_taxcredit1`, `gross_income`, `rate`, `user_qualify_taxcredit2`, `amount`, `tax`, `Refund`.

And for the inline-defined `cal_tax_owed` function, unknown variables are: `GROSS_INCOME`, `RATE` (Python is case-sensitive!), and `tax`.

So if you want to do anything with that piece of code, you should really rethink what you are trying to do..

#### edit

Because I have a good day, this is probably a solution you were trying to achieve. Without really understanding what you are trying to do, I’ve tried to get it working. Apart from the `user_qualify_taxcredit1` and `user_qualify_taxcredit2` everything is calculated. I hope it helps.

```
# this should come from somewhere
user_qualify_taxcredit1 = False
user_qualify_taxcredit2 = False

def calc_tax_rate(gross_income):
    if gross_income < 10000:
        return 0.01
    elif gross_income >= 10001 and gross_income <= 30000:
        return 0.10 
    elif gross_income >= 30001 and gross_income <= 50000:
        return 0.15
    elif gross_income >= 50001 and gross_income <= 100000:
        return 0.20
    else:
        return 0.25

def calc_tax_owed(gross_income, rate):
    if user_qualify_taxcredit1:
        return (gross_income * rate) - 1000
    elif user_qualify_taxcredit2:
        return (gross_income * rate) - 3000
    else:
        return gross_income * rate

def main():
    gross_income = int(input('enter the users gross income: '))
    print('user\'s gross income is $', format(gross_income, '.2f'))

    rate = calc_tax_rate(gross_income)
    tax_owed = calc_tax_owed(gross_income, rate)

    if tax_owed > 0:
        print('The tax owed is $', format(tax_owed, '.2f'))
    else:
        print('user receives refund of $', format(-tax_owed, '.2f'))

main()
```

Comment: Then you should finally give some more detailed information *what* does not work.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing your `main()` routine does is get and print the gross amount.  You need to add the appropriate calls to the other functions.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.

```
C:\home\python>python test.py
enter the users gross income: 4000
users gross income is $ 4000.00

C:\home\python>
```